# Created from Vuejs is called on every second

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I am emitting an EventBus from a component and it's listened multiple times.
My goal is to call a method if a certain route is changed.

```
//First component  (App.vue -> from there I user router-view)
  watch: {
    $route(to, from) {
      if (from.name == "NewGame") {
        EventBus.$emit("changeRoute", true);
      }
    }
  },

//Second one
  created() {
    EventBus.$on("changeRoute", payload => {
      this.myMethod(); //this is called several times
    });
  },


- Ex. of flow:
- Access (on access I have a get request) and leave second component ->(EventBus is called) x1 
- If I do this again ->(EventBus is called) x2  
- Again ->(EventBus is called) x3 (and now I have 3 post request with 3 distinct data, that I get every time when I access the second component.)
```

Comment: Can you try moving the ```$route...``` from the first component's ```watch``` to its ```created()```?

Answer (score 0):

In your first component, why don't you just use `mounted` or `destroyed` hooks to check for required route changes.

```
mounted() {
 if (this.$route.path === "NewGame") {
   EventBus.$emit("changeRoute", true);
 }
}
```

Comment: I need to find when user try to change route from "NewGame" .This is emitted when I on that route.

Comment: @Beusebiu, then instead of `mounted` you can use `destroyed` hook to check while leaving/exiting the component.

Comment: I edited the post, with the flow. Every time when I access the second component I have +1 (post request)

Comment: From what I tested the EventBus.$on is called +1  every time, in created a simple console.log is called just once.

Answer (score 0):

I found out a solution that works for me. I have to user `$once` insted of `$on`

```
EventBus.$once("changeRoute", payload => {
  this.myMethod();  //now is called just once
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the following after your `created()`:

```js
destroyed() {
  EventBus.$off("changeRoute", payload => {
    this.myMethod();
  });
},
```

Notice that instead of `$on` I wrote `$off`, this will remove the event listener.
Make sure that when you attach a listener, to always remove it when the component is destroyed, otherwise events will be registered several times.

Not entirely sure this will fix your problem as we do not have the full context on how you are using the components, but hopefully it fixes your problem.